# Excel pie charts from pivot table columns

Tags: excel, charts, pivot-table

I have a pivot table from a database that looks something like this:

```
         Person A       Person B        Person C

Task A      1                               3  
Task B                      1               2 
Task C      2               1.5             1
```

The number is time spent on a task.  If it's blank, the person didn't work on that task.

I would like to make a pie chart for each Person from the pivot table for time spent on each task, not including tasks where the cell is blank.  I've tried adding various flavours of pie charts but it only ever creates the chart on the first column of the table.  And when it does that, it seems to include empty cells in its key (though obviously not on the pie).

Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the Pivot Chart will attempt to plot whatever is in the Pivot Table (including all column titles).  I think the easiest way to deal with this is to add a Slicer so that you can select the Person and have it filter the data for you.  Alternatively, you can filter the Pivot Table on your own, but the Slicer is quite clean in this application.

I don't think it is possible to get multiple pie charts inside a single chart.  You could use the doughnut plot if you want to see all columns plotted at once.  Visually, that chart is horrible to interpret though.

Here is something similar to your data with the Slicer in place for person B.  Note that the legend cleans up also since the missing keys have been filtered out of the Pivot Table itself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Byron.  My user is quite happy with this it turns out.